# PowerShell CSV, take a specific row from each line and combine it into one CSV

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have 300 CSV files all separated in a directory.

I want to get one specific criteria from each CSV and put it into another using PowerShell.

This is the line I have, but doesn't seem to work.

`Get-ChildItem -Filter "*Results.csv" | Get-Content | Where-Object {$_.NAME -eq "Cage,Johnny"} | Add-Content "test.csv"`

I filtered for the specific CSVs I wanted in my directory with gci, Got the content of each using Get-Content and Where the value is Johnny Cage in the NAME column, and Add-Content into a test.csv file but doesn't work.
Any help would be great!

Comment: `Get-Content` doesn’t convert text to custom objects with properties. You need `Import-CSV` for that

Answer (score 4):

You need to deserialize your CSV text into objects with properties that can be referenced. Then you can compare the `Name` property. You can do the following if all your csv files have the same headers.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*Results.csv" | Foreach-Object {
    Import-Csv $_.FullName |
        Where-Object {$_.NAME -eq "Cage,Johnny"} } |
            Export-Csv "test.csv"
```

If your CSV files contain different headers, then you have a couple of options. One, you could create your output CSV with all possible headers that exist across all files (or just the headers you want as long as they are the same across all files). Second, you could just output your data rows and have a broken CSV.

```
# Broken CSV Approach
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*Results.csv" | Foreach-Object {
    Import-Csv $_.FullName |
        Where-Object {$_.NAME -eq "Cage,Johnny"}} | Foreach-Object {
            $_ | ConvertTo-Csv -Notype | Select-Object -Skip 1
        } | Add-Content test.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for this and your explanation is clear and precise.

Comment: I tried this today and it didn't seem to work.. I really had thought it would. I got an error message of "Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both." .. Seems like it failed at the Import-Csv

+

Comment: @PeterHui I updated the code. Note that PowerShell Core does not have that bug that requires piping to `Foreach-Object`.

Comment: I tried to do this exercise using Power Query and got a data error. I tried to do this in R with vroom and got a column mismatch error. I tried do the the same w power automate but can't figure out how to get it to work. Power Shell did this with just some minor trouble shooting. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

```
Get-ChildItem  -Filter *Results.csv |
    ForEach-Object{
        Import-Csv $_.NAME | ? { $_.EMPLID -eq "Cage,Johnny"}
    } | Export-Csv "test.csv"
```